# Attaching httpHandler to httpclientFactory webapi aspnetcore 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I am trying to attach an handler to httpclientfactory using "ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler"

but when I look inside the HttpClient to see 
if the handler is there i cannot find it

Am I attaching the handler correctly?

Any Suggesions

```
     services.AddHttpClient<IGitHubClient,GitHubClient>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
            });


    public interface IGitHubClient
    {
        Task<string> GetData();
    }

    public class GitHubClient : IGitHubClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public GitHubClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _client = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetData()
        {
            return await _client.GetStringAsync("/");
        }
    }

    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IGitHubClient _gitHubClient;;

        public ValuesController(IGitHubClient gitHubClient)
        {
            _gitHubClient = gitHubClient;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
        {
            //my _gitHubClient has no Handler attached!!!

            string result = await _gitHubClient.GetData();
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have shown is the recommend approach.

Comment: The comment about `_gitHubClient` seems like a misunderstanding. `_gitHubClient` is your abstraction that is wrapping a `HttpClient` instance. It is that instance that would have the handler.

Comment: yes correct.is it possible to  have a wrapper round httpclient and attach the handler to it. if so how should I change the "addHttpClient" bit.I would like to have a wrapper round as I do few things in there

Comment: What you currently have is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown is the recommend approach.

The comment about `_gitHubClient`

> //my _gitHubClient has no Handler attached!!!

seems like a misunderstanding.

`_gitHubClient` is your abstraction that is wrapping a `HttpClient` instance in its `GitHubClient` implementation.

```
public class GitHubClient : IGitHubClient {
    private readonly HttpClient _client; //<< Handler will be attached to this instance

    public GitHubClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
        _client = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetData() {
        return await _client.GetStringAsync("/");
    }
}
```

It is that wrapped instance that would have the attached handler.

Based on the current configuration, whenever the framework has to create an instance of the `IGitHubClient` derived `GitHubClient` for injection, the factory will create a `HttpClient` using the settings provided at start up. Which would also include adding the `HttpClientHandler` provided by `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler`

Comment: thanks for your reply and time. Actually you are right the handler was always there but in the inner-inner-etc..

Comment: However in my test calling this other api when looking at Request.Connection = {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultConnectionInfo} I cannot find the handler .where is this located on request

Comment: @developer9969 I have a similar question. Did you think about creating an extension method to configure a custom HTTP client and if so, how would an additional HTTP client handler be used in such a scenario from DI? I have posted a question on this topic as well. You may check my account and open the latest question.